# Simplicity/testability dilemma

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, software-design

Let's take a look at following class:

```
class X {
    public void execute(Data[] data) {
        for (Data d : data) {
            MyExecutor e = new MyExecutor(d);
            e.execute();
        }
    }
}
```

It's quite simple, but totally untestable if using *Mockito*. Solution is simple: introduce *ExecutorFactory* and DI it into *X*.

But it means, that instead of four classes to implement new feature you are required to write 8, plus tests... in short, simple things become total hell.

**Question:** How to rethink example above right to keep development/testing simple, but still durable?

**Update:** *MyExecutor* has nothing to do with threads and *ExecutorService*. It's just some class, which consumes *d*, but doesn't change data in any way.

Comment: @JoopEggen Please, check an update.

Comment: The method do is only a loop. What is more important to test is MyExecutor directly.

Comment: @OliverWatkins You are talking "it's too simple, what is there to test?" - but it's still some functionality and how to be sure that it's not affected by code changes if it's not test-covered?

Comment: test coverage is not an exacty science. I would say write the more comprehensive tests directly against MyExecuter, and then just have a simple test that hits the 'do' method. That should cover it.

Comment: This is a trick question: `do` is reserved, so the class doesn't compile. ;-)

Comment: @HenryKeiter You got me ;-)